# Read current drive of batch file and use drive name in command

Tags: batch-file

I have the following problem: We send customers a USB-stick with content that they need to import onto a Linux-computer via a import-function (no influence on the Linux-part, only on the USB-stick part). The Linux import-function cannot read files with spaces, i.e. the file "system volume information" which is created on every drive of a Windows computer disrupts the import function. 
With a google research I found out, how I can delete this file on the drive of the USB-Stick. If I do that before disconnecting the USB-stick from my Windows computer, I can import the content on the Linux computer. I do this with a batch-file containing the following command:

rd /s /q D:\"system volume information"

However, those USB-Sticks are sent out to customers that will want to view the content on a Windows-computer as well, before importing it, i.e. the file "system volume information" is created anew. I would like to make it as simple as possible for the customer and put a batch-file on the stick where they simply have to double-click on it in order to delete the file. This is where my problem lies: I cannot be sure, that it will be drive D: where the stick will lie. This is why I am looking for a function or command that reads the drive of the batch-file (USB-Stick) and does the command of delete "system volume information". I read some things about %~d0 but I could not find out how I specifically have to write the command to make it work.

Would you be able to help me? I have very limited experience with batches, so I apologize if this question seems very easy for you.

Thanks
Milak

Comment: The directory `System Volume Information` is created by Windows only on NTFS volumes. Use as file system on your USB sticks FAT32 or exFAT if that is possible and no batch file would be needed at all for the deletion of this directory. For an explanation of `%~d0` (drive of argument 0 - the batch file name) or `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0) open a command prompt window, run there `call /?` and read the output help for this command used in general to call a batch file from another batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the code:

```
@echo off
set P=%~d0
set "P=%P%\system volume information"
rd /s /q "%P%"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I needed. The only thing I changed was to add an extra " to the code: 
@echo off
set P=%~d0
set "P=%P%\"system volume information"
rd /s /q %P%